# Tricky CakePHP Relation with FormHelper

Tags: php, cakephp

On the current problem set I'm currently working with 3 separate models:

- Ticket
- TicketResponse
- TicketStatus

I'm working within the Tickets' `view.ctp` file. On the view, I've created a form to allow TicketResponses that are owned by the currently viewed Ticket. All of that is already working.

(Ex: .../tickets/view/1 --> Any/all ticket responses will automatigically have ticket_id set to 1)

I'm trying now to provide a way for users designated as ticket assignees the ability to close the ticket upon reply (thus forcing a reason or answer when closing the ticket). The check for assignee of whether to display this control is already working, but commented out as I'm having difficulty getting the select box (to select the available ticket statuses) to be populated with the appropriate data from the database. **Currently the select box is entirely empty.**

Issue:
Because the responses on the form (of the ticket `view` page) are primarily there only for creating new `TicketResponses`, I set the form creation to the `TicketResponse` model and `add` action. The `TicketStatus` however has a relation to `Ticket`, and not to `TicketResponse`. I'm not sure how to build the form to allow the TicketStatus to populate the data.

Models:
Ticket belongsTo TicketStatus
Ticket hasMany TicketResponse

TicketResponse belongsTo Ticket

TicketStatus hasMany Ticket

The current code I'm trying (and is rendering a select box with no values) is as follows:

```
<?php
    echo $this->Form->create('TicketResponse', array('type' => 'file', 'class' => 'form', 'controller' => 'TicketResponse', 'action' => 'add'));
    echo $this->Form->input('ticket_id', array('default' => $ticket['Ticket']['id'], 'readonly' => 'readonly', 'type'=>'hidden'));
    echo $this->Form->input('content', array(
        'label' => 'Description',
        'placeholder'=>'Describe the issue in full. Paste any screenshots in to this field, or attach them if saved to a file.',
        'required' => 'required'
    ));

    // THIS IS THE PROBLEM LINE HERE
    echo $this->Form->input('ticket_status_id');
    // THIS IS THE PROBLEM LINE HERE

    echo $this->Form->end('Submit');
?>
```

If anyone has any thoughts, I'd love to hear 'em!

As of right now I'm planning on just manually sending the data (all available ticket statuses) from the Ticket controller to the view and setting the current status based on what's returned from the current Ticket id data. I'll then caress the data and use saveAll or saveAssociated in the TicketResponse add action to get it to save the status back to Ticket.

As was requested in a comment, here is my current controller code (for Ticket view). Please note that there are more associations/models than was defined for the subset of the problem, but they should not cause any issue to the underlying problem I am identifying here. The `find('list')` was recently added to attempt a manual solution to what CakePHP would normally do automagically (what I'm trying to get it to do here):
    helpers[] = 'Time';

```
        $this->Ticket->id = $id;
        if (!$this->Ticket->exists()) {
            throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid ticket'));
        }

        // Set proper associations as req'd for the view
        $this->Ticket->recursive = -1;

        // Set the user's name as a proper concatenation for easier printing
        $this->Ticket->User->virtualFields['name'] = 'CONCAT(User.firstName, " ", User.lastName)';

        $this->set('ticket', $this->Ticket->find('first', array(
            'contain' => array(
                'Group.name',
                'User.name',
                'TicketStatus',
                'TicketPriority',
                'TicketResponse' => array(
                    'TicketAttachment' => array(
                        'fields' => array(
                            'id',
                            'ticket_response_id',
                            'location',
                            'filename',
                            'filesize'
                        )
                    ),
                    'User' => array(
                        'fields' => array(
                            'name',
                            'title'
                        )
                    )
                ),
                'TicketWatcher' => array(
                    'User.name'
                )
            ),
            'conditions' => array(
                'Ticket.id' => $id
            )
        )));

        // "FIX" for current issue where CakePHP's magic isn't working as expected
        #$this->set('ticketStatuses', $this->Ticket->TicketStatus->find('list'));

        // Update the view count by 1, if not AJAX
        if(!$this->RequestHandler->isAjax()){
            $currentViews = $this->Ticket->read('viewcount', $id);
            $currentViews = $currentViews['Ticket']['viewcount'];
            $this->Ticket->saveField('viewcount', $currentViews + 1);
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: I'm not sure your problem is in the view. You need to show your controller code.

Comment: It sounds like you are asking how to have the person (ticket assignee) change the status of a ticket when they create a Response. If so, I would add another field to your TicketResponse storing the person's choice of ticket statuses (Use this as a historical reference regarding who changed the ticket status.) Then in the controller after creating the TicketResponse, have the controller simply update the Ticket's status_id with that value (e.g., `saveField` or write a method to wrap the logic - `$this->TicketResponse->Ticket->updateStatus($ticket_id, $status_id)`)

Comment: Initially that was how I had my model schema planned out. I then realized that compared to the number of times a ticket status would change (considering the small number of people with the ability to be assigned and how often they'd actually make a change), and how often there would be responses, it was a large waste of space when I could store it once in the ticket. Although nice, we decided we didn't need historical data on the ticket status changes.

Instead of getting Cake to understand what it is that I'm doing I'll manually send the data from the Ticket controller and manipulate the data

Comment: I changed my mind. I actually was storing (and using) ticket status in the TicketResponse table, but as a plaintext reference (which realistically takes up more space). Now using an unsigned tinyint (id range of 0-254) and will basically do what you suggested. It's unfortunately not an answer to the question/problem I am having though, so I can't mark it as an answer. If an answer is presented, I would still use it in the view.